# How to load data from Amazon Redshift database to Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, amazon-redshift

I need to load the 100 millions records from a Redshift database into ElasticSearch.

I tried by creating a console application in ASP.NET Core that load the data from Redshift and bulk inserts into Elasticsearch. But it's not working, I keep getting request timeout during loading of the data or bulk insert of the data, and most importantly, it is taking too much time.

Can anyone help me to provide the best solution to load the 100 millions records from Redshift database into ElasticSearch?